# How to disable autoscreenshot of window when app switching in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

How to disable autoscreenshot of window when app switching in iOS 6 ?

I am launching app in iOS 5, and switching to other app with 5 fingers (slide gesture). Then back to first app, and while app is scrolling, i see a Default.png image. This is good.

But in iOS 6, while app is coming, i see a screenshot of app window, it seems, which was made when app is go to background. This is bad, because screenshot was made in old time and showing to user wrong image, and after app is activating, image is changing at quickly to true. In some case, screenshot is actually, but after 2-3 tryes, screenshot is very old.

Anybody knows, how to disable autoscreenshot OR maybe resolve problem with screenshot, for screenshot will be do at every time, when app is switching?

Thanks

Comment: The provision is there in iOS 7 it seems.